# JavaScript {..a} - что это такое?

Tags: javascript

Что может значить {..a} в JS`е? Я не смог найти никакой информации...

Comment: деструктуризацию объекта. Только не две .., а три ...

Comment: Покажи полный пример того, где это увидел

Comment: [Rest in Object Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: Мне это скинули просто как тему, которая будет на собеседовании :D Спасибо большое, выручил)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{...obj}` - это поверхностное копирование (shallow copy) объекта без сохранения прототипа и неперечислимых свойств. Для реализации использована деструкторизация, но фактически получается то же самое, что при использовании `Object.assign({}, obj)`.

Answer (score -2):

Это деструктуризация объекта. Вот тут хорошо написано: https://learn.javascript.ru/destructuring-assignment#destrukturizatsiya-obekta